# Reference and pointer in polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, polymorphism

Base abstract class:

```
class Satellite
{
public:
    Satellite();
    virtual void center()=0;
    virtual ~Satellite(){}
};
```

First derived class

```
class Comm_sat:public Satellite
{
public:
    Comm_sat();
    void center() override{cout << "comm satellite override\n";}
};
```

Second derived class

```
class Space_station:public Satellite
{
public:
    Space_station();
    void center() override{cout << "space station override\n";}
};
```

Pointer version of the functions

```
void f(Satellite* ms){
    ms->center();
    delete ms;
}

int main()
{
    Comm_sat* cs = new Comm_sat;
    Space_station* ss = new Space_station;
    f(cs);
    f(ss);
}
```

The objects created using `new` in `main()` are properly destroyed in `f()`, right?

Reference version of the functions

```
void f(Satellite& ms){
    ms.center();
}

int main()
{
    Comm_sat cs;
    Space_station ss;
    f(cs);
    f(ss);
}
```

Is the reference version better?

Besides, I try to use `unique_ptr`, however, I get errors

```
void f(Satellite* ms){
    ms->center();
}

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Comm_sat> cs{new Comm_sat};
    unique_ptr<Space_station> ss{new Space_station};
    f(cs);
    f(ss);
}
```

> Error: cannot convert `std::unique_ptr<Comm_sat>` to `Satellite*` for argument `1` to `void f(Satellite*)` 
>   Error: type `class std::unique_ptr<Comm_sat>` argument given to `delete`, expected pointer `delete cs`;

Same error for the other derived class.

Comment: `void main` is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the reference version better?

Yes, although a better way to put this would be "the pointer version is worse". The problem with the pointer version is that you pass it a valid pointer, and get a dangling pointer when the function returns. This is not intuitive, and leads to maintenance headaches when someone modifies your code thinking that you have forgotten to delete `cs` and `ss` in the `main`, not realizing that `f` deletes its argument.

The version that uses a reference is much better in this respect, because the resources are managed automatically for you. Readers of your code do not need to track the place where the memory of `cs` and `ss` gets released, because the allocation and release happen automatically.

> I try to use `unique_ptr`, however, I get errors

There is no implicit conversion from `std::unique_ptr<T>` to `T*`. You need to call [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) if you want to pass a raw pointer:

```
f(cs.get());
f(ss.get());
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, in either case (pointer or reference), objects are allocated on heap, not on stack, right?

Comment: @MiloLu The version that uses references allocates both `cs` and `ss` objects on the stack.

Comment: As Useless suggested, I can allocate object on the heap, and still pass `*cs` and `*ss` by reference. It seems to me an address is just an address, it doesn't matter it's on heap or stack.

Comment: @MiloLu This is up to you. An advantage of allocating on the stack is that you do not need to track the lifetime of the object and call `delete`. The disadvantage of stack allocation is that you cannot extend the lifetime of the object past the runtime of the block in which it has been allocated.

Comment: Other than that, stack is faster than heap, which again makes the reference version preferred?

Comment: @MiloLu Stack allocation is "faster" only in absolute terms: it definitely takes fewer CPU cycles. However, situations when it makes a lot of difference are rare, so the initial considerations must center around *your* convenience (readability, maintainability, extensibility, ease of debugging), not the CPU cycles.

Comment: Let's say, I allocate one on stack `ss`, one on heap `*cs`, and pass both of them by reference. It seem the vtbl can handle that without any complaints.

Comment: @MiloLu Of course, virtual dispatch will handle both cases just fine. However, vtbl has nothing to do with tracking lifetime of an object, which is an important difference that I am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

> The objects created using `new` in `main()` are properly destroyed in `f()`, right?

They're destroyed, and cleaned up correctly, yes. "Properly" is a stretch though, since all this manual-new-and-delete-raw-pointers stuff is poor style.

The reason `unique_ptr` isn't working for you is that ... it's a `unique_ptr`, not a raw pointer. You can't just pass it as a raw pointer.

Try

```
void f(Satellite* ms){
    ms->center();
}
// ...
f(cs.get());
```

or better, unless you really need to pass `nullptr` sometimes,

```
void f(Satellite& ms){
    ms.center();
}
// ...
f(*cs);
```

or best of all, since you don't show any reason to require dynamic allocation at all:

```
void f(Satellite& ms);
// ...
{
    Comm_sat cs;
    f(cs);
} // no new, no delete, cs goes out of scope here
```